# Converting large files in python

Tags: python, database, large-files, large-data

I have a few files that are ~64GB in size that I think I would like to convert to hdf5 format. I was wondering what the best approach for doing so would be? Reading line-by-line seems to take more than 4 hours, so I was thinking of using multiprocessing in sequence, but was hoping for some direction on what would be the most efficient way without resorting to hadoop. Any help would be very much appreciated. (and thank you in advance)

Comment: If you can read blocks of data without scanning for lines you can speed things up because you don't have to scan every character, but seeing your implementation would make it easier to make suggestions.

Comment: I'm just doing a `for line in fd:` approach. After that right now I just check to make sure I'm picking out the right sort of data, which is very short; I'm not writing anywhere, and it's taking around 4 hours to complete with that. I can't read blocks of data because the blocks in this weird file format I'm reading are not standard, it switches between three different sizes... and you can only tell which by reading the first few characters of the block.

Comment: just as an idea: read large chunks into a `mmap`'ed file an parse the lines read from memory. reading from RAM then can be more efficient when using multiple threads.

Comment: consider using an external (dumb, fast) converter, like `h5import` http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/Tools.html#Tools-Import

Comment: This question is most suitable for programmers.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3):

For this type of problem I typically turn from Python. You're right that multiprocessing/parallelization is a good solution, but Python is *not pleasant* to work with in this area. Consider trying something on the JVM. I like Clojure's [core.async](https://github.com/clojure/core.async), but there's also the [peach](http://peach.rubyforge.org/) ("parallel each") or [celluloid](http://celluloid.io/) libraries for JRuby that's much closer to Python.

The approach doesn't have to be as "heavy" as Hadoop, but I'd still use a similar map/reduce pattern over the files.  Have a thread that is reading line by line from the source file(s) and dispatching to several threads.  (Using core.async I'd have multiple queues which are getting consumed by different threads, then feeding back a "finished" signal into a watchdog thread.) In the end you should be able to squeeze a lot of performance out of your CPU.